# Using setInterval() in C++

Tags: c++

In JavaScript, there is a function called `setInterval()`. Can it be achieved in C++? If a loop is used, the program does not continue but keeps calling the function.

```
while(true) {
    Sleep(1000);
    func();
}
cout<<"Never printed";
```

Comment: `void setInterval() {}`... but I assume you are asking for the *functionality* of the JavaScript function as well... so what exactly would that be? --- Nevermind, [found its docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: Short answer: Yes, it can be achieved. Longer answer: To really emulate the JavaScript `setInterval` functionality you need to implement some form of synchronization context and dispatching system, since JavaScript is single-threaded, so all invocations of handlers of `setInterval` are dispatched to the "main" thread. This is non-trivial to implement from scratch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no built in `setInterval` in C++. you can imitate this function with asynchronous function:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void setInterval(std::atomic_bool& cancelToken,size_t interval,F&& f, Args&&... args){
  cancelToken.store(true);
  auto cb = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f),std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  std::async(std::launch::async,[=,&cancelToken]()mutable{
     while (cancelToken.load()){
        cb();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
     }
  });
}
```

use `cancelToken` to cancel the interval with

```
cancelToken.store(false);
```

do notice though, that this mchanism construct a new thread for the task. it is not usable for many interval functions. in this case, I'd use already written thread-pool with some sort of time-measurment mechanism.

Edit : example use:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::atomic_bool b;
    setInterval(b, 1000, printf, "hi there\n");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example to illustrate how to use it?

Comment: Perfect example of the strengths of C++: butt-ugly on the inside, really nice interface on the outside.

Comment: @DevSolar: Yeah, this example encourages me to explore more about C++. +1

Comment: What is the purpose of using `std::bind` here? Does this has any advantage over just writing `f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` inside the while loop?

Comment: This does not replicate JavaScript's `setInterval`. This implementation drifts. For one, it doesn't account for the time it takes to execute `cb()`/`f()`, nor does it respect the semantics of `sleep_for`. This may or may not be an issue, but it should be pointed out in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::thread` to achieve.

```
// <thread> should have been included
void setInterval(auto function,int interval) {
    thread th([&]() {
        while(true) {
            Sleep(interval);
            function();
        }
    });
    th.detach();
}
//...
setInterval([]() {
    cout<<"1 sec past\n";
},
1000);
```

Comment: Next nitpick: No include for, and platform-specific, function `Sleep()`. I suggest using [`sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) instead.

Comment: why it said `thread was not declared in this scope` i'm using `g++ -std=c++11` compiler