# do code 60 times per second c++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm a bit new to c++ and wondering how I can do this code 60 times per second:

```
if (x >= 500 && y >= 500)
{
    x = 1;
    y = 1;
}

if (x <= 500)
{
    x = x + 1;
}

else
{
    y = y + 1;
    x = 1;
}

gfx.PutPixel(x, y, R, 0, 255);
```

I know it's a pretty amateur code, but this is the way I want to start learning it. I already tried doing a while loop, but it ended up rather freezing or stopping at it's end.
The purpose of this code Is basically creating a screen with pixels changing color by +1 each time it loops.

Are there an easier way to do it?
Would love if you would include some improvements too.

Comment: you'd need `thrd_sleep` and measuring time. Or a SDL-like framework with timer functions.

Comment: u can add a sleep of 16 millisecs between each loop iteration. I would  #include <unistd.h> and use usleep(microseconds);

Comment: @sramij That would drift by quite a bit by the inaccuracy of 16ms alone (since the the actual value is 16.666...), but the code running before the sleep would take up a bit of time, meaning it would nearly always take an incorrect amount of time.

Comment: The standard solution to this particular problem is to render as fast as you can. The rendered image is based on the current timestamp (relative to some starting point).

Comment: [**This seems to solve this problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33234557/5768335)

Comment: @sramij: You need to differentiate between accuracy and precision. Just because `usleep` takes a parameter with microsecond precision, doesn't guarantee microsecond accuracy. (And in case you discover the C++ way - `std::chrono` - the same holds true here as well.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using setInterval() in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234403/using-setinterval-in-c)

Comment: Hmm.. It seams like it doesn't want to display anything unless it finishes the loop. I've tried several of your answers, but I think the problem relies on the code rather then the Sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is wrap this in a `while(true) {...}` loop.

Next, to throttle it down to 60 times a second, you could do something like this at the end of the loop:

```
while(true)
{
    // Place all your code here

    std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(16)); // Sleep 16 ms
}
```

Comment: that's not a regulated wait. You're sleeping at least 16 ms so you drift. And the OP code is not instantaneous either.

Comment: You are 100% correct, this is just a general way to do it. If you really want exactly 60 fps you'd have to time the code and account for it.

Comment: more like it. But the regulation is still an important factor. With your knowledge of C++ std lib you can do better (I'm not the downvoter BTW). For instance using `std::clock()` maybe, from the other answer that got downvoted also then deleted...

Comment: 16ms is too inaccurate - it would be 40ms too fast after only 60 frames, and 2.4 seconds off after one minute, not to mention that his code doesn't run instantaneously as @Jean-FrançoisFabre said.

Comment: come on, I'm begging for an answer now. don't make me write my own :)

Comment: I understand all the implications of using a 16 ms sleep. If OP wants, he can use this to get pretty close to 60 FPS. If not, he can wait for a longer, more accurate answer.

Comment: ... or equally short, and accurate.

Comment: I think this is a good enough answer for the purpose. Upvoted. I'd use `16ms`.

Comment: [**This seems to solve this problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33234557/5768335)

Comment: @GEEF your downvote got cancelled and you were upvoted: you deserve it, because it was really difficult to dig out the duplicate

Comment: Hmm, Do I need any kind of extra stuff to this?
I'm getting red lines under this_thread and chrono

Comment: @Typewar you will need to ensure you include the necessary libraries. See the #includes in this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/this_thread/sleep_for/

Comment: @Typewar: Or [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) for a more reliable reference.

Comment: @IInspectable TIL: cplusplus.com is not a reliable reference?

Comment: @GEEF: You'd have to ask someone that believes it isn't.